# Xamarin build error

Tags: android, xamarin, build

I'm using Xamarin in with Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10 64 bit. When building the project it shows the below warning:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(283,2): warning : Error: no package specified
```

It doesn't stop me from building and deploying but I'm not fond of errors anyway.

How to deal with such an error?

Comment: I believe this happens when there is no package name in your `AndroidManifest.xml` set. Double check there is one set in your `Android Options`. Otherwise a recent fix might've already resolved this harmless warning: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/commit/8337d21ebeff738b281912a9615514705c79037c

Comment: Can you please provide more information, is your project a sample project? Can you please try a blank project?

Comment: No, it's a project I inherited. Will check that recent fix, thanks